# Desktop resolution issues

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I have windows 7, a ATI Radeon 6750 and a Samsung 22inch A350H display.

I have it connected using a HDMI cable and resolution of 1920x1080 works fine.

Problem is I want to downsize, 1920x1080 is 16:9 so I try to downscale it to 1600x900 (reason being performance in games). But when I resize it to that size I get 2 big black bars, one on each side of the screen.

I have tried using ATI's CCC but coudn't find a solution there.

Anyone has any suggestion here what the issue could be? Thanks in forward

Comment: It's almost certainly the display itself doing that.  It may be that it doesn't support pixel scaling like this.

Answer (score 1):

***1600x900*** does not seem to be a supported resolution on the A350. I'd reckon you fall further back and use ***1366x768*** instead which should be supported.

Also most games would only support 1366x768 / 1920x1080 but nothing in between, so the 1366x768 is a safer bet anyway.

Comment: Going down to 1360x768 results in the same issues with a black bar on either side, looking at documentation http://www.samsung.com/nl/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/monitors/led/LS22A350HS/EN-spec . Is it possible that it only allows 1920x1080?

Comment: @Tjirp have you adjusted the overscan?  did you try changing the refresh rate? did you adjust the pixel format? http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/GPU-10-SupportedResolutionsUnavailableforMonitor.aspx  I am not saying there is any hope. Most of the HDMI devices no mater how poor will at least do the 1080 & 720  1280x720 .

Comment: Heh, the overscan sets itself to about 10% when switching to a resolution lower then 1920x1080 (no idea why) but selecting 1600x900 and then manually adjusting the overscan back to 0% fixes it.